OECD Package Malfunctioning
Does anyone know if the OECD 0.2.5 library still works? As of July 2, the OECD migrated its databases to a new portal, and now all the data I previously downloaded is unavailable. Here is an example:
library(OECD)
df <- get_dataset("EPL_OV", 
                  filter = list(c("DEU", "FRA"), 
                                c("EPRC_V1", "EPRC_V2")), 
                  start_time = 2008, end_time = 2010)

Can anyone share their experience with this?

If you have having problems with that package, you can file an issue with the package author on github: https://github.com/expersso/OECD/issues

The package doesn't work currently because the functions still query the legacy API endpoints instead of the new ones (e.g., stats.oecd.org should now be sdmx.oecd.org). The functions could be updated based on documentation here and here, but it's not clear whether this package is actively maintained anymore...
